# SQL Aggregate function with join and distinct output

Tags: sql

List the names of companies owned, as well as the number of shares authorized, the total shares outstanding,
and outstanding shares as a % of authorized shares. Sort the output by company name.

```
  SELECT c.name,
         sa.authorized,
         ROUND(css.total_outstanding/css.current_authorized * 100, 2)  AS "Outstanding"
    FROM company c JOIN 
         shares_authorized sa ON sa.stock_id = c.stock_id JOIN 
         current_stock_stats css ON css.stock_id = sa.stock_id
ORDER BY c.name;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJI04.png)

Attached is the output.
I need seven rows 7nrows as answer and not 8. New york times should be combined.
Using SUM returns error with Group By.
What else could we use here?

Comment: SELECT
    c.name,
    sa.authorized,
    ROUND(css.total_outstanding/css.current_authorized * 100, 2)  AS "Outstanding"
FROM company c
    JOIN shares_authorized sa
        ON sa.stock_id = c.stock_id
    JOIN current_stock_stats css
        ON css.stock_id = sa.stock_id

ORDER BY c.name
;
Actual Code

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a GROUP BY on c.name and
sa.authorized and an AVG (if that's what you're looking for) of ROUND(css.total_outstanding/css.current_authorized * 100, 2).

Best wishes,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name, authorized, ROUND(total_outstanding / current_authorized * 100, 2) AS "Outstanding"
FROM (
    SELECT c.name
        ,sa.authorized
        ,SUM(css.total_outstanding) AS total_outstanding
        ,SUM(css.current_authorized) AS current_authorized
    FROM company c
    JOIN shares_authorized sa ON sa.stock_id = c.stock_id
    JOIN current_stock_stats css ON css.stock_id = sa.stock_id
    GROUP BY c.name, sa.authorized
) TMP
ORDER BY name, authorized
```

Comment: thanks for different approach. however, it returns 8 rows and not 7.